# /usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 4: docker: not found

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, shell

Building a docker image using a file called pipeline.sh, however I am receiving an error message stating:
**/usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 4: docker: not found**

Pipeline.sh file

```
#! /bin/sh

#***Sample Script to build, test and push containerized Node.js applications ***

#build docker image

docker image build -t $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG .

#Run all unit tests

docker container run $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG npm test

#Login to docker Hub

docker Login -u $HUB_USER -p $HUB_PWD

#Push the image to Docker Hub

docker image push $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG
```

---

Docker Image File:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update $$ apk add docker

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/

CMD /usr/src/pipeline.sh
```

---

Command:

```
PS C:\Users\tab45\fod\ch08\builder> docker container run --rm --name builder 

-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 

-v /c/users/tab45/fod/ch08/sample-app:/usr/src/app 

-e HUB_USER='username' 

-e HUB_PWD='password' 

-e repository='ch08-sample-app' builder:1.0
```

---

Output

```
/usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 4: docker: not found

/usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 6: docker: not found

/usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 8: docker: not found

/usr/src/pipeline.sh: line 10: docker: not found
```

[codeoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQlof.png)

Comment: Is Docker installed? Like, if you type in `docker` into a terminal, what happens?

Comment: Yes Docker is installed. If I run docker --version I see the following:  Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086

Comment: Is docker installed inside the image?

Comment: This is the docker file I am using to build the image                                                          FROM alpine:latest  \

RUN apk update $$ apk add docker \

WORKDIR /usr/src/app \

COPY . /usr/src/ \

CMD /usr/src/pipeline.sh

Comment: `$$` should be `&&`

Comment: I have replicated in my local creating the image, it worked fine with both $$ and &&. Check building the image `docker build -t test Dockerfile` and then run the docker run command

Comment: Specify the absolute to `docker`, or set the variable `PATH` in your shell script., so that it contains the directory where `docker` is stored.